# How can I remove the right margin of the last <i>?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I tried `:last-child {margin-right: 0;}` but it didn't work.

```css
.navigation-menu .social-icons i {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<div class="social-icons">
  <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector for that should be

```
.navigation-menu .social-icons a:last-child i { ... }
```

You are adressing the `i` inside the *last*  `a` element inside the `.social-icons` div, so the `:last-child` has to be appended to the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

please add following style

```
.social-icons i:last-child{
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```